# Can I use hadoop to train a neutral network?

Tags: hadoop, distributed-computing, perceptron, neural-network

I want to train a neural network with the help of Hadoop. We know when training a neural network, weights to each neuron are altered every iteration, and each iteration depends on the previous. I'm new to Hadoop and don't quite familiar with features it provides. Can I chaining the iteration with the help of method `addDependingJob()` emphasizing the dependences? Or there's other tricks can be used to implement the NN with help of Hadoop.

Any advice will be highly appreciated.

Thanks and Best Regards.

Comment: I think there was a proposal for it on the Mahout mailing list a while back but was never implemented: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MAHOUT-364. The last I heard about it people were looking for a Neuroph (http://neuroph.sourceforge.net/) plug-in for Hadoop.

Comment: I heard the Neuroph thing got accepted as a GSoC project, but I don't know any more than that.

Comment: If your looking for a REALLY fast way to train a ANN on a big dataset, you should probably look into programming backprop on GPUs. Much larger speed up than Hadoop on comparable hardware due to easy vectorization for ANNs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write it by youself. If you know how to write Bacvk propogation in single core from scratch. It can be easily migrated to Mapreduce approach. HDFS cache should store current neuron weights and each map job should evaluate their update upon training instance and then reduce should sum all this updates and put them to cachce.